# How to put legend on the right side using grid.arrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2

how do I get the 4 plots to be displayed in a 2x2 pattern, without their legend, which is then placed far right, centered between rows 1 and 2. So in a third column so to speak.

```
a=mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour=hp)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_smooth(se=F, colour="grey")
b=mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour=hp)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_smooth(se=F, colour="grey")
c=mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour=hp)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_smooth(se=F, colour="grey")
d=mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour=hp)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_smooth(se=F, colour="grey")

grid.arrange(a, b, c ,d, ncol = 2)
```

Searched the web and stack

Comment: libraries {patchwork} and {cowplot} will be helpful. Also see `facet_grid` and `facet_wrap` to generate and arrange multiple ggplots for all combinations of levels of one or two factors

Answer (score 0):

Update see OP request:

Just change `widths` in `grid.arrange()` like:

```
.....
# Arrange the plots
grid.arrange(
  arrangeGrob(a, b, c, d, ncol = 2),
  legend,
  ncol = 3,
  widths = c(8, 2, 0)  # Adjust to desired proportions
)
```

[image]
First answer:
We could do it like this using `gridExtra` and `cowplot` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)

# Create the 4 plots without a legend
a <- mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour=hp)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_smooth(se=F, colour="grey") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

b <- mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour=hp)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_smooth(se=F, colour="grey")  +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

c <- mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour=hp)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_smooth(se=F, colour="grey")  +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

d <- mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour=hp)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_smooth(se=F, colour="grey")  +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

# Create a separate legend
legend <- get_legend(
  mtcars %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour=hp)) +
    geom_point(size=2) +
    geom_smooth(se=F, colour="grey"))

# Arrange the plots
grid.arrange(
  arrangeGrob(a, b, c, d, ncol = 2),
  legend,
  ncol = 3,
  widths = c(4, 4, 1)  # Adjust to desired proportions
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to "cut away" some of the white to the right of de legend? That not so much of the plot is white.